# Is there a column-min-width and column-max-count in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/, but it only lets you specify `column-width` and `column-count`, potentially both (either individually, or through `columns`), but does not define any kind of way to specify, say, minimum width and maximum count.

For example, on the [category index of OpenBSD ports](http://ports.su/), there are 71 categories, generally fitting in 9em.

If I use `ul {-moz-column-width: 9em;}`, then at 89em and above, there'd be at least 9 columns (89em = 9 × (column-width of 9em) + 8 × (column-gap of 1em)), making each column contain very few categories, and, IMHO, making it more difficult to navigate, since, even though the text would "look" left-to-right, you'd still have to navigate top-to-bottom.  (Or is there a way to have a list of columns going left to right, instead of top-to-bottom?)

If I instead use `-moz-column-count: 8;`, then the site will be less usable on smaller screens, below about 70em or so.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can use `@media` queries to specify different rules for different screens.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

```
ul { -moz-columns: 9em; }

@media (min-width: 89em) {
  ul { -moz-columns: 8; }
}
```

Comment: you had -moz-columns instead of -moz-column-width.  And actually, now that I'm looking again, inside the media query you should really have -moz-column-count.  and while we're at it, the -webkit vendor prefixes, and the non-prefixed versions.

Comment: @andi, I still don't understand what the typo is.  Is `-moz-columns: 9em` not working for you for some reason?  it works here just fine.

Comment: hmm, you know what - my mistake.  It wasn't working for me at first, and I somehow assumed that the shorthand was buggy or something, but now that I'm testing it again, it's fine.  I must have had a typo myself when I originally tested.  I'm sorry - go ahead and roll back.