# Is there a way to up-size the font with CSS to fit the screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

I'm thinking about improving the front page of the [OpenBSD ports](http://ports.openbsd.su/) web-site, which lists about 71 categories of the ports.

My idea is to use a couple of columns (maybe `ul {-moz-columns: 9em;}` [also with a limit to at most 8 columns at 89em and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972656/is-there-a-column-min-width-and-column-max-count-in-css3/29972657#29972657), `@media (min-width: 89em) {ul {-moz-columns: 8;}}`, effectively specifying that there should be at most `8` columns with a minimum width of `9em`), and add some `padding`/`margin` to each list item listing a port, but on bigger screens, this might occupy too little screen and leave too much empty space.

Is there a way to automatically upsize the font of certain elements, to fill up all the available space, but without effecting the size of some other elements?  For example, I'd like to have the heading and the categories up-sized, but leave all the credits at the bottom of the page in their normal font.  I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.  (I guess I could place in a couple of specific `@media` rules for a few jumps up a size, but I was curious if there's a more flexible and automated solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

You can you vw (viewport width) or wh (viewport height) where 1 v == 1% of the initial containing block

Example:

```
 p{
     font-size: 4vw;
 }
```

Comment: Wrapping this into media query would be a good idea, because on small screens it may go too small.

Comment: cool!  having one `@media` query is better than having several, thanks!  (it's also probably better to have it within `@media` for those older browsers that would have no idea what it is.)

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175730/how-to-properly-use-css-values-viewport-relative-lengths.  It seems like it's not very obvious how to ensure that font-size in `vw` units won't end up being below `1em`.